# Impale the [vlad]!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

I've noticed that the tag [vlad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vlad) is used ambiguously in the following two cases:

- [Vlad the deployer](http://docs.seattlerb.org/vlad/), an application deployment automation for Ruby/Rake?
- [VLAD (vector of locally aggregated descriptors)](http://www.vlfeat.org/api/vlad-fundamentals.html), an encoding/descriptor vector which is used e.g. in image retrieval.

The [vlad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vlad) tag currently has 27 questions, where most of the questions (~20) appear to be about Vlad the deployer, and the rest is about the VLAD vector.

The [vlad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vlad) tag has no tag wiki and no excerpt, which provide guidance on when to use it (i.e. should it be used for questions on Vlad the deployer, the VLAD vector - or maybe even for questions on the [Dracula theme](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42915911/4221706)?)

I think we should split [vlad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vlad) into two separate tags, maybe [vlad-deployer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vlad-deployer) and [vlad-vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vlad-vector). Do you agree, or would it be a better idea to allow the [vlad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vlad) to live on?

Comment: There is also Dracula. :)

Comment: @Neolisk As I've seen less pun titles in the past months, I itentionally did *not* make the title something along "Impale the [vlad]" :)

Comment: The no pun rule is applied to only [featured] posts (and is enforced by mods). Do keep the love of puns burni[nat]ing in our hearts.

Comment: I'm just here for the Pun of it

Comment: Impalement was quite a nasty Punishment...

Comment: As members of the Lounge, this has a special meaning to us. Thank you very much.

Comment: Vlad like to impale others, not the other way around. The title really as impact. Since Vlad deployer have more than 2/3 of the questions, we can continue to have the [vlad] tag and the new [vlad-vector] tag.

Comment: @PedroPolonia thanks for this idea. Could you add it as an answer please, so the community can vote which option they prefer?

Comment: @hbaderts done :)

Comment: @Neolisk there also is [Bacula](http://blog.bacula.org/)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Differentiate between the two things for which the tag is being used, so that it is clear what is intended. As the OP suggests, "split `vlad` into two separate tags, maybe `vlad-deployer` and `vlad-vector`".

**Edit**: This answer is essentially a motivation for [another answer that complements it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349095/2225787).

Answer (score 12):

While tag wiki matters, the truth is that many people seem to just grab the first tag that looks slightly related without really bothering much further.

This suggests that we need to:

- split the tag in two: `vlad-deployer` and `vlad-vector` sound OK (though there's redundancy in the latter case),
- black-list `vlad`, to prevent its re-introduction.

Answer (score -6):

Since Vlad deployer have more than 2/3 of the questions, we can continue to have the [vlad] tag and the new [vlad-vector] tag.

The two tags should have wiki and excerpt.

Comment: The issue with tag wiki is that most of us dont have 20.000 reputation to edit the wiki. Already propose vlad wiki entry.

Comment: Unfortunately, people using VLAD (the vector) are likely to just use the vlad tag without reading the wiki, so it might be worth *enforcing* the distinction.